# Find CSV files using glob function in python :

Tags: python, csv, glob

*Relatively new to Python
-- I have several  csv files at dir2. I only want csv files starting with myfile_xxx.csv . I want to use glob.glob and print names of all csv files available starting with myfile.
Here is the code I used*

```
   import glob
   path = "C:/Users/dir1/dir2"
   os.chdir(path)
   print(os.getcwd())
   for filenames in sorted(glob.glob('path/myfile?.csv')):
       print(filenames)
```

*Output doesn't print filenames.
What is wrong here ...?*

Answer (score 1):

The `?` syntax matches only a single character, so you can instead a string like: `glob.glob('path/myfile_???.csv')`, assuming the suffix after the underscore is always a three-digit number.

Comment: What should I use instead of ? if I have more than three digit number after underscore ?

Comment: @VPER A single asterisk (*) matches any number of characters. You can also create ranges, for instance like so: `[0-9]`. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29